# Lower semi-continuity of particular function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $F : \mathbb{R}^n \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set-valued map, locally bounded, upper semi-continuous, and taking nonempty, convex and compact values. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
\begin{equation}
f(F(x)) = \min_{y \in F(x)} \lVert y \rVert.
\end{equation}
How can I show that the map $x \mapsto f(F(x))$ is lower semi-continuous?

Comment: What you want to prove is that the epigraph is closed. Does that help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *What you have*: Set-valued upper semicontinuity is defined as the openness of $\{ x : \phi(x)\subset U\}$ for every open set $U$.
2. *What you want*: The lower semicontinuity of $f\circ F $ means that for every $r$, the set $\{x:f(F(x))>r\}$ is open. Let's rephrase this to be more similar to 1): for every $r>0$, the set $\{x:F(x)\subset \{y:|y|>r\}\}$ is open. Note this relies on the compactness of $F(x)$.

Now it should be clear that 1) implies 2). The assumption that $F(x)$ is convex is redundant.